# alignas specifier: on the type / on the member data

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer, memory-alignment, alignas

Are the following two cases equivalent in all situations?

**1) `alignas` on the type**

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t Alignment>
struct alignas(Alignment) A
{
    T data[N];
};
```

**2) `alignas` on the member array**

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t Alignment>
struct A
{
    alignas(Alignment) T data[N];
};
```

Comment: If `T` is `char` and the structure also contained a `double`, the results could be different, I suspect, especially if `N` is odd.  At the least, that's the sort of scenario that I suspect would create differences — numerous details to be resolved which is why this is comment and not answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a language lawyer perspective, they are not equivalent. The layout of a class is implementation-defined, and there are few guarantees. One guarantee is that if `T` is a standard-layout type, then both versions of your `A` class are standard-layout types, which implies that they do not have padding at the beginning ([[class.mem.general]/27](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#27)). Depending on the alignment you specify, `A` might have to have padding at the end to ensure that its size is a multiple of that alignment. But there is no guarantee in the standard that the implementation uses the smallest amount of padding necessary. For example, if `T` has an alignment requirement of 4 and `N` is 3, and you requested an alignment of 8, then either `A` class could have 4, or 12, or 20, ... bytes of padding at the end. *In practice*, the implementation will use the smallest amount of padding necessary, and the two versions of your `A` will have the same layout.

If `T` is not a standard-layout type, the implementation is allowed to insert padding at the beginning of `A`, although it's unlikely that an implementation would actually do so. The amount of padding the implementation inserts may differ between the two versions of your `A`.

Practical considerations generally force two struct types that have a *common initial sequence* to have the same offset for corresponding data members in order to implement [[class.mem.general]/26](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#26) efficiently. Consider, for example:

```
struct T1 {
    int t11;
    int t12;
};
struct T2 {
    int t21;
    int t22;
};
union U {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
};
int foo(const U& u) {
    return u.t1.t12;
}
```

The standard requires that, if `u`'s active member is actually `t2` instead of `t1`, then this code behaves as if it returns `u.t2.t22`. In order to implement this, the compiler will ensure that `t12`'s offset within `T1` is the same as `t22`'s offset within `T2`, and simply access the `int` that is located at that offset from the address of `u`.

But if I'm speaking as a language lawyer, I have to say that the standard does not guarantee this. A C++ implementation could, conceivably, give `T1` and `T2` different layouts, store some extra information somewhere that lets it keep track of the active member of a `U` object, and when it evaluates `u.t1.t12`, check if the active member is `t2`, and if it is, then use the offset of `t22` instead of that of `t12`.

In practice, all known C++ implementations will give the common initial sequence of two standard-layout structs equal offsets for corresponding members. However, your `A` is only standard-layout when `T` is standard-layout, and even when your `A`'s are standard-layout, the common initial sequence of the two different versions of `A` is not guaranteed to include the `data` member because, in the case where the alignment specifier is applied to `A` itself, it is not clear what the standard considers the alignment requirement of the `data` member is, and that means [[class.mem.general]/23.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#23.2) might not be satisfied.

All that being said, I would find it surprising if any implementation laid out the two versions of your `A` differently (given identical template arguments). Practically speaking, you *can* depend on them having the same layout, but you *shouldn't*, because I see no good reason to not just write what you mean. Do you care about the alignment of `A`, or the alignment of its member? Whichever one you actually care about, write that. Or, if you care about both, you can put the `alignas` in both places.